# Can VMware ESXi be configured to use LDAP user database?

Tags: ldap, vmware-esx, vmware-esxi, pam

We are using VMware server 2 on linux debian at the moment. We may move to ESXi for better performance, but we use authentication for console access using our ldap directory (via PAM).

Can you do this with ESX/ESXi, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not for local users on ESXi, but you can LDAP integrate vCentre to allow management.

EDIT - ESXi 4.1 can now authenticate directly with LDAP/AD.

Answer (score 0):

According to various sources around the web, the next release of ESXi, version 4.1, will have Likewise embedded in it, which will allow you to integrate with Active Directory:

http://www.likewise.com/community/index.php/forums/viewthread/542/